# The sound "ka" or "cha" or "kha" means what ? e.g Khaalesi,Khan,Chan,Kaan

Tags: etymology, sound-symbolism

Especially in east geography (middle east, middle asia, asia) the words starting with Kha, ka, cha means like a leader or a king or a lord.

Khaalesi (game of thrones character who living in east of the game of thrones map)

Khan (old Turkic-Mongolian word e.g. Genghis Khan)

Kaan (old Turkish leaders e.g. Bumin Kaan/Kağan, Kağan)

Is this sound meaning anything like leader or lord ?

Comment: A phone alone never means anything. Several of the words mentioned **do** have common etymology, but it has nothing to do with the phone `[kh]` itself.

Comment: It is possible that they are all related. Either Martin or Peterson could have deliberately coined *khal* based on *khan*. Which has nothing to do with [x].

Comment: One of these things is not like the others... since "khaalesi" is from a fictional language, it's obviously not historically related to any real languages. (As user6726 mentions, it might have been based on words from real languages, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 5):

**Sounds have no meaning per se.**  Besides a few [ideophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideophone), human language is arbitrary.

See: [duality of patterning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_articulation)

The word *[khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khan_(title))* is a bastardisation of *[khagan/kağan/қаған/خاقان‎‎/可汗](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khagan)*, the [ultimate origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouran_Khaganate) of which is likely Mongolic.  There are many such cognates floating around Asia, beginning about 1500 years ago, and in Europe, beginning about 1000 years ago.  There is a tendency to mythologise these things, but it is not much more interesting nor older nor more widespread today than *sir*, *sire*, *senior*, *señor*, *signore*, *[sénos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/s%C3%A9nos)*... or *ustâ*, *ოსტატი*, *استاد*, *استا*, *остаз*, *[استاد](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%AF#Persian)*...

(Names of fictional characters are of course just that - names of fictional characters.)

Comment: [Sound doesn't convey meaning](https://imgur.com/a/WCtpz), eh? Paging [Dr. Lawler](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf).....

Comment: We can talk about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism but there is still no inherent universal meaning to those sounds associated with those classes per se.

Comment: There are decent arguments generally but, pardon, many problems with the list you posted.

Comment: That's like saying written words have no meaning because spelling is arbitrary. Of course spelling is arbitrary (by the aptly named principle of the arbitrary sign), but words still have the meanings we ascribe to them. That's what meaning means. Similarly, phones have the meanings we ascribe to them, the semantics they convey when uttered. For example, in English, something like 400 words starting with *sn* relate to the idea of a nose.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/per_se#English

Comment: I do not consider the established -- and, here, particularly relevant -- connection between sound and meaning to be an "extraneous consideration" with respect to either this question or your answer to it, in the sense employed by that Wiktionary definition. Though in the case of OP's *khan* et al, I expect it's not phonoestheme/phonosemantics at play here, but more likely a etymological connection (maybe lost to history). Up to and including the fictional character name (which was likely modeled, consciously or unconsciously, on the *khan* sound).

Comment: I suggest you make a new separate question on this.